# Deploy different roles on different servers using one playbook

Tags: linux, ansible

F.e. I created two roles via "ansible-galaxy init": deploy_back and deploy_front

Also I wrote a playbook.yml file.

```
- name: Create cluster
  become: yes
  hosts: all

  roles:
  - deploy_front
  - deploy_back
```

If I launch it via "ansible-playbook playbook.yml" - then on both servers gonna be deployed two roles. How can I deploy different roles on different servers in one playbook?

If I write playbook.yml

```
- name: Create cluster
  become: yes

  hosts: front
  roles:
  - deploy_front

  hosts: db
  roles:
  - deploy_db
```

then outputs looks like "*...found a duplicate dict key (hosts)... found a duplicate dict key (roles).... Using last defined value only*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must separate your `hosts:` and other declarations into different plays. The code should look something like this:

```
- name: Create front cluster
  become: yes
  hosts: front
  roles:
  - deploy_front

- name: Create db cluster
  become: yes
  remote_user: different-db-user
  hosts: db
  roles:
  - deploy_db
```

Comment: Thanks, But how can I give a general name to entire work (including deploying db, front, back servers) ?

Comment: Put the 1st play (Create front cluster) into playbook1.yml and the 2nd play (Create db cluster) into playbook2.yml. Create playbook.yml (General Central ...) and [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#import-playbook-import-a-playbook) playbook1.yml and playbook2.yml.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get a message of "duplicate key" is due how the YAML is structured.

A playbook is a collection of plays, in the form of an ordered list.  Each play is specified by a series of keyword/value pairs.  Common **play** keywords are: `name`, `hosts`, `become`, and `roles`, to name a few.

In YAML, to specify different items in a list, you use the dash (`-`) character.  In both of your example `playbook.xml` playbooks, you only have one left-most dash character.  That means you only have a one item list for a playbook, or a one play playbook.

If you add a dash character before your second `hosts` declaration in to your second example `playbook.yml`, you will have a valid playbook that now contains two plays:

```
- name: Create cluster
  become: yes

  hosts: front
  roles:
  - deploy_front

- hosts: db
  roles:
  - deploy_db
```

In your original second example, only a single play is defined.  Moreover, both the `hosts` and the `roles` keyword is defined twice in that one play.  YAML is complaining that you have two different definitions for both the `hosts` and `roles` keyword.